# jQuery button toggle issue with .click()

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

I would like to create a button that when .click() removes a class and adds another one. Ultimately I would like the the two buttons to change their background colors when I click one and the other.

html

```
<button id="addBot" class="bot"><span>+</span></button>
<button id="subBot" class="bot"><span>-</span></button>
```

css

```
.bot {
    border-color: #3071a9;
    border-style: solid;    
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
}
.blue1 {
    background-color: #3071a9;
}

.white1 {
    background-color: #ffffff;  
}
```

js

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //1 is blue
            //0 is white
            var addColor = 1;
            var subColor = 0;
            $('#addBot').addClass('blue1');
            $('#subBot').addClass('white1');

            $('#addBot').click(function() {
                if(addColor == 1) {
                    $('#addBot').removeClass('blue1');
                    $('#addBot').addClass('white1');
                    addColor = 0;
                } else {
                    $('#addBot').removeClass('white1');
                    $('#addBot').addClass('blue1');
                    addColor = 1;
                }
            });
        }
```

***Note*** This code does "work". When I click my button it does change to the different color but only for a split second then switches back immediately. I have also tried using .on('click', function() {}) and that does not work either.

Comment: Did you mean to have any of the #addBot's to be subBot in the if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify further without the var add color

```js
var addColor = 1;
            var subColor = 0;
            $('#addBot').addClass('blue1');

            $('#addBot').click(function() {
                $('#addBot').toggleClass('blue1');
            });
```

```css
.bot {
    border-color: #3071a9;
    border-style: solid;    
    border-width: 1.5px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;  
}
.blue1 {
    background-color: #3071a9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addBot" class="bot"><span>+</span></button>
<button id="subBot" class="bot"><span>-</span></button>
```